# open multiple files in one emacs window

Tags: macos, terminal

I can open a file in emacs with this command:

```
open -a Emacs main.cpp
```

But when I apply the same command to multiple files

```
open -a Emacs main.cpp test.cpp
```

two emacs windows will appear. I would like to open them
in the same emacs window, is this possible?

Comment: One window or one instance (one running Emacs application)?

Comment: One window, multiple buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of starting Emacs with `open` you can use `emacsclient` to send files to an already running Emacs. For this to work you need to start the corresponding server inside emacs by including

```
(server-start)
```

in your emacs init file.